# transmit vs macfusion (osx), a remote drive using Git

Tags: macos, git, sshfs

I am a developer and I needed to create a remote drive. At first time it was not problem because I would use Panic Transmit to mount the drive with SSH connection. And I could open, edit and save any file normally.

But this project is using Git (Version Control), so that I couldn't add/commit nothing into repository. If I try commit I get an Input/Output Error.

If I try connect to a server and commit directly there, I couldn't because I dont have credentials there. I need to commit it using my computer. So that I must have the remote drive.

I only get the right way using macfuse/macfusion. Anyone can give any explanation, or have any idea, about that ? Did I do something wrong in Transmit ?